# Bluetooth reverse tethering

Tags: reverse-tether

Hey all so I have connected my HTC to my laptop via Bluetooth ( they're paired and connected)

- the Bluetooth Tethering option in the phone is Enabled
- I can see a Bluetooth network connection has been added in network
  connections and adapter panel
- I'm stuck after this....
- the problem is that when I go to the sharing tab of the network
  connection which I'm trying to share it's internet, there it asks you
  to select a network connection which the internet is going to be
  shared too but the Bluetooth connection wont show so I could select
  it...

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth reverse tethering for Android on Windows 7/8/10 is not possible *out of the box*. It *might* be if you have installed the Toshiba Bluetooth Stack (see below).

As of Windows 10 1809 the Bluetooth PAN network generated by Windows' own BT drivers technically is not a "full blown" network like wired LAN or WiFi. Thus it does not show up in the list of network adapters to use the shared internet connection.

For the same reason you cannot bridge your wired LAN ethernet adapter with the bluetooth PAN (Microsoft documentation says bridging needs two "highspeed" connections - which PAN obviously is not).

As some googling reveals Mac and Linux folks are better off because these OSes *can* do reverse tethering with bluetooth.

If you really desperately need to do it based on a windows machine your only choice is to **set up a virtual machine with Linux as guest OS** and do it from there. There is a how-to in German on this solution at [PC-Welt](https://www.pcwelt.de/tipps/Internetverbindung-ueber-Bluetooth-8356639.html).